# Concurrent exception in Groovy even when changes are made to another LinkedHashMap

Tags: java, groovy, each, linkedhashmap, concurrentmodification

**I have created a new LinkedHashMap 'workingStrData' using 'strData' and I still get the error.**

I am trying to remove some items from this LinkedHashMap based of another list.

The way strData is structured is

```
    strData = [components[{key1:value1}{key2:value2}...]]     

    def workingStrData = new LinkedHashMap(strData)
    List componentsToRemove = ['item1','item2'...]
    int itemsRemoved = 0

    workingStrData.components.eachWithIndex {
            comp, workingStrIndex ->
                println("Index: "+workingStrIndex+" Component: "+comp.number)

                def baditem = comp.number in componentsToRemove
                if (baditem) {
                    strData.components.remove(workingStrIndex - itemsRemoved)
                    itemsRemoved += 1
                }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot remove an element from a list while iterating with `each` or with `eachWithIndex` which by the way is a bad practice. Groovy offers much more elegant and simpler solutions.

As suggested, try `retainAll()` or as suggested here, try `removeAll()`:

```
def strData = [
    components : [
        [number: 'item0'],
        [number: 'item1']
    ]
]

def componentsToRemove = [
    'item1','item2'
]

componentsToRemove.each { removeIt ->
    strData.components.removeAll { it.number == removeIt }
}

assert strData.components == [[number: 'item0']]
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not complaining about the `strData`/`workingStrData` maps, it is complaining about the `List` referenced by the value of the `"components"` key in the map.

You know, the `List` you are actually iterating, and the `List` you actually call `remove(int index)` on.

You don't actually iterate or modify the map, so copying that is meaningless.

Answer (score 0):

Eddiel is right, you can't modify array ( and strData.components is an array ) while you iterate it.

Even if you created a copy of root map `def workingStrData = new LinkedHashMap(strData)` the content of this map referencing the same data.

it means that `workingStrData.components` and `strData.components` referencing the same array.

---

groovy styled code to modify array:

```javascript
def strData = [
    components:[
        [number:'111', name:'aaa'],
        [number:'222', name:'bbb'],
        [number:'333', name:'ccc'],
        [number:'444', name:'ddd'],
    ]
]
List componentsToRemove = ['222','333']

//--------------------------------------
// if you want to keep original data:
def modData = [
    components: strData.components.findAll{c-> c.number in componentsToRemove }
]

println "original           : $strData"
println "modified           : $modData"

//--------------------------------------
// if you want to modify existing data
strData.components.retainAll{c-> !( c.number in componentsToRemove) }
println "original (modified): $strData"
```

Answer (score -1):

You can not modify the map unless you use an `iterator` or you use a synchronized collection. This is by design in Java. Check https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#synchronizedMap-java.util.Map- to wrap your collection or, remove the elements using the iterator's own remove function.

In java, that would look like this:

```java
Iterator<String> iterator = workingStrData.keySet().iterator();
while (iterator.hasNext()) {
    iterator.next();
    iterator.remove();
}

// workingStrData is empty at this point.
```

Comment: The code isn't modifying the `strData` map, it is modifying a nested list, stored as the value of the key `"components"` in the `strData` map.